# Index of Array in php

Tags: javascript, php

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $isbn => $qty ) : $conn = db_connect();
   $book = mysqli_fetch_assoc(getBookByIsbn($conn, $isbn));
```

I want to echo the index of array `$_SESSION['cart']` but no logic works.

Any help?

Comment: First: Move your connection outside the foreach. You can reuse the connection to the database inside the loop. Second: `echo $isbn;` gives you the index-key.

Comment: You can find the "index" of an array value with `array_keys()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: I think if an array is of arrays then you can do something like `SESSION['cart'][1]` . Please post the results you get.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a variable outside the loop and count from there. Increase the variable in each iteration of Foreach.

```
<?php    
$arrIndex = 0;
foreach($data as $key=>$val) {

    //Loop body
    echo $arrIndex;
    $arrIndex++;
}
```